# how to change the navigation item color when it will active?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My css style I have

```
#nav {
    position: relative;

}
```

and html code is

```
<div class="header-background">
        <!-- <div> -->
         <div id="logo">Site Title</div>

         <div id="nav">
               <nav id="desktop-nav">
            <a class="nav-item" href="#1">about</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#2">news</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#3">Community</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#4">Docs</a>
           </nav>

    </div>
```

here I have about,news,community,docs these 4 field..I want when I click any button suppose **"about"** that time **"about"** button color change to **yellow** and  **other buttons** text color will **white**...
So,I am using the jquery

```
 $(".desktop-nav a").live("click",function(){
    $(".desktop-nav a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

but the color is not changing..guys suggest me something..

Comment: live function is deprecated use .on() or .click() instead

Comment: And use '#' ID selector instead class selector '.' http://jsfiddle.net/kjkkuxdh/

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

According to your HTML code, nav tag has id not class.

here is the working code:

```
$("#desktop-nav a").on("click", function(){
    $("#desktop-nav a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do as nevermind suggested: Use the correct selector.

Also, you could use the `.siblings()` function of jQuery to make your code more generic.

```js
$("#desktop-nav").on("click", 'a', function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `jQuery` code doesn't work because it does not bode well with your html.
You seem to have got your jQuery selector wrong.

So, I'd suggest a couple of changes :

**First change:** the `nav` element has an id of `desktop-nav`. Your `jQuery` code method is looking for a class named `desktop-nav`. This maybe a typo.

**Second change :** as stated before `live` method is deprecated. You can either use `on()` or `click()` method. I have used `click()` method in my example.

If you make the first change, you code should work i.e replacing `.desktop-nav` with `#desktop-nav` in jQuery.

The second change will ensure compliance with best proactices.

See the code working below :

```js
$("#desktop-nav a").click(function(){
     $("#desktop-nav a").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
 });
```

```css
#nav {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    display:-webkit-box;
}
#nav, #nav * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.nav-item {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.active {
    color: #82b965;
}
/* Desktop */
 #desktop-nav .nav-item {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: color 200ms linear;
    transition: color 200ms linear;
}
#desktop-nav .nav-item:hover, #desktop-nav .nav-item:active {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-background">
    <!-- <div> -->
    <div id="logo">Site Title</div>
    <div id="nav">
        <nav id="desktop-nav"> 
            <a class="nav-item" href="#1">about</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#2">news</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#3">Community</a>
            <a class="nav-item" href="#4">Docs</a>
        </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: In your code it is working..But in my html file it is not working.. saying "Uncaught ReferenceError:$ is not defined"

Comment: @preeti If it says $ undefined, then most probably the `jQuery` reference is missing. Just check if the jQuery file is being loaded on the page.

Comment: I got it..i put the jquery code inside document{}..now it is working

Comment: Glad to help!!! If my answer helped you, you can mark it as the answer so as to help others who stumble upon this question!!